# Getting Error: cannot import name 'DB' from partially initialized module. Not finding the circular import issue

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, spacy

I'm working on a assignment for school.

But When I try to run the flask app I get some kind of circular import error. I've been trying to go back and remove things step by step while still keeping my project functional. I've hit a wall:

> Usage: **main**.py run [OPTIONS]
> Error: While importing 'Help.app', an ImportError was raised:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   FileUsage: **main**.py run [OPTIONS]
>
> Error: While importing 'Help.app', an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/chris/Help/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line
> 256, in locate_app
>
> ```
> __import__(module_name)   File "/home/chris/Help/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
> from .app import create_app
> ```
>
> File "/home/chris/Help/app.py", line 5, in 
> from .models import DB, User, insert_example_users
>
> File "/home/chris/Help/models.py", line 3, in 
> from .twitter import add_or_update_user
>
> File "/home/chris/Help/twitter.py", line 5, in 
> from .models import DB, Tweet, User
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'DB' from partially initialized module
> 'Help.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (/home/chris/Help/models.py)

app.py file:

```
# Main app/routing file for Twitoff

from os import getenv
from flask import Flask, render_template
from .models import DB, User, insert_example_users


# creates application
def create_app():
    # Creating and configuring an instance of the Flask application
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = getenv("DATABASE_URI")
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

    DB.init_app(app)

    # TODO - Make rest of application
    @app.route('/')
    def root():
        DB.drop_all()
        DB.create_all()

        insert_example_users()

        return render_template("base.html", title="home", users=User.query.all())

    @app.route("/update")
    def update():
        insert_example_users()
        return render_template("base.html", title="home", users=User.query.all())

    @app.route("/reset")
    def reset():
        DB.drop_all()
        DB.create_all()
        return render_template(
            "base.html",
            title="home",
        )


    return app
```

Twitter.py file:

```
"""Retrieve tweets and users then create embeddings and populate DB"""
from os import getenv
import tweepy
import spacy
from .models import DB, Tweet, User

# TODO - Don't include raw keys and tokens (create .env file)
TWITTER_API_KEY = getenv("TWITTER_API_KEY")
TWITTER_API_SECRET_KEY = getenv("TWITTER_API_SECRET_KEY")
TWITTER_OAUTH = tweepy.oAuthHandler(TWITTER_API_KEY, TWITTER_API_SECRET_KEY)
TWITTER = tweepy.API(TWITTER_OAUTH)

# NLP model
nlp = spacy.load("my_model")


def vectorize_tweet(tweet_text):
    return nlp(tweet_text).vector


def add_or_update_user(username):
    try:
        twitter_user = TWITTER.get_user(username)
        db_user = (User.query.get(twitter_user.id)) or User(
            id=twitter_user.id, name=username
        )
        DB.session.add(db_user)
        tweets = twitter_user.timeline(
            count=200, exclude_replies=True, include_rts=False, tweet_mode="extended"
        )

        if tweets:
            db_user.newest_tweet_id = tweets[0].id

        for tweet in tweets:
            vectorized_tweet = vectorize_tweet(tweet.full_text)
            db_tweet = Tweet(id=tweet.id, text=tweet.full_text, vect=vectorized_tweet)
            db_user.tweets.append(db_tweet)
            DB.session.add(db_tweet)

        DB.session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {username}: {e}")
        raise e
```

models.py file:

```
""""SQLAlchemy models and utility functions for Twitoff Application"""
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .twitter import add_or_update_user


DB = SQLAlchemy()


class User(DB.Model):
    """Twitter User table that will correspond to tweets - SQLAlchemy syntax"""
    id = DB.Column(DB.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = DB.Column(DB.String, nullable=False)
    newest_tweet_id = DB.Column(DB.BigInteger)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User:{self.name}>"


class Tweet(DB.Model):
    """tweet text data - associated with User table"""
    id = DB.Column(DB.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    text = DB.Column(DB.Unicode(290))
    vect = DB.Column(DB.PickleType, nullable=False)
    user_id = DB.Column(DB.BigInteger, DB.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    user = DB.relationship("User", backref=DB.backref('tweets', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Tweet: {self.text}"


def insert_example_users():
    """We will get an error if we run this twice without dropping & creating"""
    users = ["elonmusk", "geoffkeighley", "iamjohnoliver", "neiltyson"]
    for user in users:
        DB.session.add(add_or_update_user(user))
    DB.session.commit()
```

**init**.py file:

```
from .app import create_app

APP = create_app()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place the app instance not in `__init__.py` but in `app.py`. The instance should be a WSGI callable and not a package identifier.